# Configuring maven server with proxies (proxy per server)

Tags: maven, proxy

I have a secured network which prevents any access to the Internet only through proxies. I have a different proxies for different uses.
I want to configure maven (~/.m2/settings.xml) in such a way that: each server will have a different proxy.

for example, i want to access amazon AWS through a specific proxy.
how should i change this snippet:

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>aws.amazon.com</id>
        <username>[username]</username>
        <password>[pass]</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

or is there any other place that needs to be changes?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. This is more general problem: you would need to use a PAC http://superuser.com/a/417901/487482

Comment: Do you like to download artifacts from aws ? Do you use a repository manager ?

Comment: One of the reasons i'd like to separate the proxies is because i use another proxy to access repos